# Re-assigning variables for cryptarithmetic puzzle in Prolog

Tags: prolog, cryptarithmetic-puzzle

I'm using Prolog to solve generic cryptarithmetic puzzles for a homework assignment. I'll talk about this in the context of `SEND + MORE = MONEY`.

The partial code that my professor gave me reduces the 3 input lists, i.e. `[S,E,N,D]`, `[M,O,R,E]`, `[M,O,N,E,Y]`, to a unique variable list, i.e `[S,E,N,D,M,O,R,Y]`. I've gotten it to a point where I recursively assign a unique value between 0 and 9 to each variable in the reduced list.

My question is, how do I then reassign the values in the reduced list to the values in each of the 3 input lists? My code is as follows:

```
solve_expression(L1,L2,L3) :-
    variables(L1,L2,L3,L),
    bind(L).

bind(L) :-
    assign_members(L,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),
    is_unique(L).

assign_members([],L) :-
    is_unique(L).
assign_members([H|T],L) :-
    member(H,L),
    assign_members(T,L).

is_unique([H|T]) :-
    unique(H,T),
    is_unique(T).
is_unique([]).

/** professor's code below */
unique(_,[]).
unique(X,[Y|Z]) :- 
    X \== Y,
    unique(X,Z).

merge([],L,L).
merge([X|Y],Z,[X|L]) :-
    unique(X,Z),
    !,
    merge(Y,Z,L).
merge([_|Y],Z,L) :- 
    merge(Y,Z,L).

variables(A,B,C,V) :-
    merge(A,B,W),
    merge(C,W,V).
```

Keep in mind this is for a homework assignment, so I am not looking for the answer, just a hint as to how I may accomplish this. Also, I've only been using Prolog for about a week.

Thank you!

Comment: Just make a simple unification rule. For example, `convered(A, B, [A,B]).` will unify A's and B's. For example, `A = 1, B = 2, converted(A, B, L)` yields `L = [1,2]`.

Comment: 'reassign the values' is performed by unification. You don't need anything.